# Pipette pumps durability

Tags: experimental-chemistry, equipment

According to your experience, in terms of durability and longevity of the tools, which one of these types of pipette pumps is better and why?

1. Tri-valve pipette bulb
2. Syringe pipette pump
3. Electronic pipette pump

These pipette pumps are mentioned in the YouTube video [Bio-Rad Laboratories — Using Serological Pipets](https://youtu.be/4VTTE_oWs58).

Comment: As long as the chemical is not very corrosive, medical syringes with needles are easier to use than pipettes with pumps. Medical syringe AS a pump (with help of a short silicone pipe as connector) also works good enough, but is less precise than other methods. Still, I have several years of experience using it in this capacity. It worked fine.

Comment: Which syringe are you talking about? The regular syringe?

Comment: @Rexita Yep, plain old regular medical one-use plastic syringes.  They are good enough for surprising amount of cases, and are OK as pumps for pipettes. Furthermore, medical syringes work great with https://www.plasticoid.com/sleeve-stoppers.html for works in argon atmosphere.

Comment: You mean this syringe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syringe

Comment: No screws like this, they prevent use with glass pipettes https://www.nicvape.com/syringes-blunt-tip-needle ||.  This one is better https://www.amazon.com/Pack-BDTM-Dispensing-Syringe-needle/dp/B00FUO2X06 |||You can fix a short silicone tube on it and plug it onto your pipettes. It works well enough, is cheap and actually reliable and durable (I saw one in intense use for several years as a pump).

Answer (score 1):

Syringe pipette pump.

Tri-valve is not as easy to use as syringe one. And the little metal sphere in it can be thrown while using. The syringe is more comfortable, it is just required to have 3 types for different volumes.

Additionally, when the pipette is broken at the top or has similar problems, you can somehow adapt the syringe, like inserting pipette deeper or tightening the syringe. It is also not expensive and easy to find from others when you need more.

Comment: "tightening the syringe" like at the end part of the syringe where the pipette is inserted? Isn't that part made of some kind of rigid plastic or is it rubber made? If it's rigid plastic how would you tighten that?

Comment: "when the pipette is broken at the top or has similar problems, you can somehow adapt the syringe, like inserting pipette deeper". Is it not possible to do that with the tri-valve pump?

Comment: " It is also not expensive and easy to find from others when you need more." I think this statement doesn't apply to me..

Comment: -For your first comment, it is a screwed plastic, you can loosen and tighten for your need. It is important as for instance pipetting DCM is troublesome in any other way, it just leaks without control.
-Trivalve is not as rugged as syringe ones, it will be not as effective; replying to your second comment. 
-I don't want to sound like a supplier of syringe pump but it is both more convenient and has more lifetime, it can be cheaper on that scale. In Turkey, this is the situation.